# Netty 4 HttpChunkedInput throws "unexpected message type: DefaultHttpContent" in HttpObjectEncoder

Tags: java, netty, httpserver

I wrote a netty 4.0.33 https file server that is suppose to send files as chucks. The [File-Server-Example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java) Shows when using https to handle the response like this:

```
// Write the initial line and the header.
channelHandlerContext.write(httpResponse);
// Write the content.
ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
sendFileFuture = channelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(
     new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(accessFile, 0, accessFile.length(), 8192)),     
     channelHandlerContext.newProgressivePromise()
);
```

My file I tested it with is only 270 byts long so the handler immediately fires the complete event, but with an error;

```
Transfer failed.java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: DefaultHttpContent
```

which ich caused by the **HttpObjectEncoder** class that is part of the HttpServerCodec. for some reason the **HttpChunkedInput** passes a **DefaultHttpContent** object that seems to be not allowed.

My Pipe Looks like this

```
HttpServerCodec
HttpObjectAggregator
ChunkedWriteHandler
FileHandler
```

It looks like a pretty default setup to me. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I initialized my HttpResponse object for the headers like this:

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
```

Comment: why type has the "httpResponse" ?

Comment: I added the response object initialization as an update to my inititial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create a DefaultFullHttpResponse.

Please use:

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
```

Comment: This was not expected to be the error. can you explain the difference?

Comment: if you write a FullHttp* message it contains the whole body of the message. While you try to write it in a streaming fashion, so you need to write the part of the message first that contains the headers and then stream the body.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but was impossible to be debugged with the error message i got. Thank you!

Comment: I still sometimes get the error reported in the initial question. Am I right that I need to queue incoming requests and wait until the sending of a previous request was finished? Does Http1.1 (Netty 4) not support sending responses in parallel?